# BASH: Load 1 line from text file and create an array from each "my entry 1"

Tags: bash

I have a text file that cannot be re-formatted with a single line entry:

```
"/my folder paths" "./my file paths/text.file" "my file.txt" "/my folders*/" "/myFolders/*subs/*.txt" "/my folders/files/subs*/*"
```

I want to load each "" entry into a bash(v5.2+) array.

I've tried IFS but struggling with the single delimiter that IFS uses, since the actual splt isn't exactly a single character delimter - each element is between the quotes.

1. I've tried (wont work, because each element is on a single line surrounded by double quotes, not 1 element per line):

   ```
   readarray -t pathsArray < sourcepaths.txt
   ```
2. I've tried (not sure why this didn't work)

   ```
   IFS='\a' read -ra pathsArray < <(tr '" "' '\a' < sourcepaths.txt)
   ```
3. I've tried:

   ```
   mapfile -t pathsArray < <(tr -s '" "' '\n' < sourcepaths.txt)
   ```
4. I've tried:

   ```
   IFS=$'\a'
   mapfile -t pathsArray < <(sed 's/" "/'\a'/g' sourcepaths.txt)
   ```

Ultimately, once the single lined file contents are loaded into the array, I wanted to wildcard expand them for all folders and files that actaully exist on the system.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Read a quotted string into [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) array

You have a *`file`* that contain one line:

```
"/my folder paths" "./my file paths/text.file" "my file.txt" "/my folders*/" "/myFolders/subs/.txt" "/my folders/files/subs*/*"
```

#### 1. Create array from whole file

If your file do contain only one line and you want it into an array, for this you could simply:

```bash
declare -a array="($(<file))"
```

Then, for showing content of you `$array`, you could hit:

```bash
declare -p array
```

```
declare -a array=([0]="/my folder paths" [1]="./my file paths/text.file" [2]="my
 file.txt" [3]="/my folders*/" [4]="/myFolders/subs/.txt" [5]="/my folders/files
/subs*/*")
```

Note: This will read **whole** file, so this will work same if fields are one separated lines.

Note 2: This work with quotes too!

There is another *`file`*:

```
"/my folder paths" "./my file's paths/text.file"
'my seconds".txt' "/my folders*/" "/myFolders/subs/.txt"
"/my folders/files/subs*/*"
```

Then

```bash
declare -a "array=($(<"file"))"
declare -p array
```

```
declare -a array=([0]="/my folder paths" [1]="./my file's paths/text.file" [2]="
my seconds\".txt" [3]="/my folders*/" [4]="/myFolders/subs/.txt" [5]="/my folder
s/files/subs*/*")
```

With a quote in field `[1]` and a double quote in field `[2]`!

#### 2. Create array from one line

If you have to read you file by line, you could

```bash
read -r line < "file"
declare -a array="($line)"
declare -p array
```

```
declare -a array=([0]="/my folder paths" [1]="./my file's paths/text.file")
```

For demo, with same last file:

```bash
cnt=1
while read -r line; do
    declare -a "array=($line)"
    echo "Line: $((cnt++))"
    declare -p array
done  < "file"
```

```
Line: 1
declare -a array=([0]="/my folder paths" [1]="./my file's paths/text.file")
Line: 2
declare -a array=([0]="my seconds\".txt" [1]="/my folders*/" [2]="/myFolders/sub
s/.txt")
Line: 3
declare -a array=([0]="/my folders/files/subs*/*")
```

Note 3: Using either syntax `declare -a array="($line)"` or `declare -a "array=($line)"` (having first double quote before variable name or before parenthesis) don't matter!

If you're frugal and won't define *another* variable, you could:

```
declare -a myFinalArray
read -r myFinalArray[0] <file
declare -a myFinalArray="(${myFinalArray[0]})"
```

Then `declare -p myFinalArray` for showing content of your array.

Comment: what about if that is not the only line in the file but that is the only line to be extracted?
ie the txt file contains something like this:
thearrayline = "/my folder paths" "./my file paths/text.file" "my file.txt" "/my folders*/" "/myFolders/*subs/*.txt" "/my folders/files/subs*/*"

Comment: My answer contain **two parts**!! Second part show how to read and parse **one** line!